# Add data every month/day/... in Dart

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I'm coding a a flutter app connedted to firebase/firestore. I have some datas that I would like to read everies months or week or ..., to sum it to another data.

I'm really stuck about it. How can I do or what is the function/method that I can use?

Tank you very much for your awnsers!!!!

Comment: Where did you stuck with?. Add your code as well with the question.

Comment: I just don't know what kind of function i have to use

Comment: Your question is very messy. Are you looking to fetch or update Firestore data every period of time? If you want people to answer, make it as clear as possible. Take a look at other successful posts.

Comment: Please add your a code and a snapshot of your firebase Firestore.